# How to pass parameter value for a string that is inside Variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Can some one please help me how can I pass a Parameter value into a string that is inside a Variable

Ex:

```
DECLARE @STR VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

DECLARE @ID INT

SET @STR = 'SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE STUDENT_ID=@ID'
```

Here I want to pass @ID as a parameter to Variable @STR

Answer (score 4):

Use `sp_executesql` to value to the parameter this will also avoid sql injection. Try this

```
DECLARE @STR NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

DECLARE @ID INT

SET @STR = 'SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE STUDENT_ID=@ID'

exec sp_executesql @str,'@ID INT',@ID
```

Comment: to use `sp_executesql` sql statement  must be a Unicode variable.. so @STR should be nvarchar else it will thow error..

Comment: @Mini - yep missed it

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
DECLARE @STR VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

DECLARE @ID INT

SET @STR = 'SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE STUDENT_ID=' + CAST(@ID AS VARCHAR(50))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one easy way:

```
DECLARE @STR VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

DECLARE @ID INT

SET @STR = 'SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE STUDENT_ID=@ID'

SET @STR = REPLACE(@STR, '@ID', COALESCE(CAST(@ID AS varchar(31)),''))
```

And of course there are others.   You could have used string concatenation when building `@STR`, or you could keep it the way it is and use a parameterized call to sp_executesql when you finally want to execute the string, assuming that's what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a query as:

```
DECLARE @ID int;
--to use sp_executesql sql statement  must be a Unicode variable
DECLARE @STR nvarchar(500);     
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);

/* Build the SQL string.
as a best practice you should specify column names instead of writing *
*/
SET @STR =
     N'SELECT Col1,Col2 FROM STUDENT WHERE STUDENT_ID=@ID';

SET @ParmDefinition = N'@ID Int';
/* Execute the string with the parameter value. */
SET @ID = 1;
EXECUTE sp_executesql @STR, @ParmDefinition,
                      @ID = @ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity you can also create a Store Procedure for it:-

**Code in SQL**

```
Create Proc [ProcedureName]
    @ID As int
As

SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE STUDENT_ID=@ID
```

**Calling a Store Procedure**

```
[ProcedureName] 1
--Here replace "1" with your Id
```

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE @STR VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

DECLARE @ID INT

SET @STR = 'SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE STUDENT_ID='+@ID

should do